# Don't maximum source and sink current of IRF4427 exist?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

The IRF4427 [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/91741/IRF/IR4427.html) has no maximum current rating for sink and source, so I don't know how large the resistance on the gate should be to limit the current.

I tried to use this IRF4427 to drive 8 IRF1404s with each channel driving 4 gates.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet does show those parameters.  When it outputs a high, it can provide a typical pulse of 2.3 A and when it outputs a low, it can sink a typical pulse of 3.3 A.  The pulse current will drop as the gate capacitance charges.  From the gate capacitance of the transistor you select,  you can calculate the pulse duration:  it's the time it takes an exponential pulse to deliver enough charge to bring the capacitance's voltage to the value \$V_B\$.  It's roughly five time constants.  You can increase this time by inserting a resistor \$R\$ between the driver output and the gate.  Using the gate capacitance \$C_g\$, the time constant is \$\tau=RC_g\$.  If you choose not to insert a resistor, use the value of the gate resistance for the transistor.

When the gate capacitance has no charge on it, the current is determined by \$V_B / R \$, where \$R\$ either is the resistance you insert (plus the gate resistance) or just the gate resistance.  It's up to you to make sure there is enough resistance present to guarantee you not attempt to exceed the source and sink currents.  To that end, you might use the minimum currents rather than the typical currents to make sure you do not violate the limits.

Comment: So if the rating is for typical. Isn't that mean i can exceed that number?

Comment: What the datasheet is telling you by providing a minimum is how much current you can count on sourcing or sinking.  If you attempt to source or sink more than this, the device is not guaranteed to be able to do it.  It is safe for you to demand less current, but not more.